# Comparar valores entre tags e filtra-los por faixa de valor em check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como fazer com que uma Input quando Checked filtrar os valores entre as tags  ? EM JQUERY

```html
<div class="Container">
<div class="Thumb-Produto" >
<img src="http://www.oqvestir.com.br/Imagens/produtos/85/00048785/00048785_Vitrine.jpg">
<div class="Thumb-Preco">
<span class="Moeda-Preco">R$</span>
<span class="Texto-Preco">50,00</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Container">
<div class="Thumb-Produto" >
<img src="http://www.oqvestir.com.br/Imagens/produtos/23/00054123/00054123_Vitrine.jpg">
<div class="Thumb-Preco">
<span class="Moeda-Preco">R$</span>
<span class="Texto-Preco">150,00</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<form>
<INPUT CLASS="FILTRO" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="OP1"> R$ 0,00 - 100,00
</form>
```

Comment: Só uma dica, Gladson, se você só escreve uma única frase solicitando código em maiúsculas, sem dizer se sabe jQuery, se tentou alguma coisa, a pergunta fica parecendo do tipo *"Trabalhem pra mim de graça"*... sei que não é sua intenção e a maioria das vezes o pessoal não tem problema em responder esse tipo de pergunta, mas fica o registro. Valeu e boa sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para selecionar os produtos que estão no intervalo de preço no `RadioButton` selecionado basta recuperar o texto atrelado. Como o próximo elemento é um nó do tipo texto, não é possível fazer isso com jQuery, logo utilizei o próprio DOM para isso.

A forma de recuperar a faixa do `RadioButton` é completamente dependente da organização. Isso é, se você mudar de lugar, vai parar de funcionar. Para isso não ocorrer, você pode usar atributos customizados para definir a faixa.

Por exemplo:

```
<INPUT CLASS="FILTRO" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="OP1" data-min="0" data-max="100"/> R$ 0,00 - 100,00
```

Basta recuperar esse valor com a função `data` do jQuery:

```
var $filtro = $('.FILTRO');
var min = $filtro.data('min');
var max = $filtro.data('max');

// Agora min e max possuem 0 e 100 respectivamente
```

Com esse valor, basta iterar sobre os containers, buscar o preço do item e verificar  se o preço dele está no intervalo.

**Meu script não foi feito com atributos customizados pois não queria gerar alterações no seu html**

Script:

```js
function buscarTextoAoLado(elemento) {
    return elemento.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
}

$('.FILTRO').on('click', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);

  var filtroMin, filtroMax;

  // Pegando o texto e quebrando
  var textoAoLado = buscarTextoAoLado($this.get(0));
  var faixaPreco = textoAoLado.substring("R$ ".length);
  var precos = faixaPreco.split(' - ');

  filtroMin = parseFloat(precos[0].replace(',', '.'));
  filtroMax = parseFloat(precos[1].replace(',', '.'));

  $('.Container').each(function(i, e) {
    var $container = $(this);
    var $textoPreco = $('.Texto-Preco', $container);
    var valor = $textoPreco.html() || $textoPreco.text() || $textoPreco.val();

    var valorFloat = parseFloat(valor.replace(',', '.'));

    if (valorFloat >= filtroMin && valorFloat <= filtroMax) {
      // Sua acao para um container que esta dentro da faixa de preco
      $container.css('border', '5px solid red');
    } else {
      // Sua acao para um container que esta fora da faixa de preco
      $container.css('border', '');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Thumb-Produto">
    <img src="http://www.oqvestir.com.br/Imagens/produtos/85/00048785/00048785_Vitrine.jpg" />
    <div class="Thumb-Preco">
      <span class="Moeda-Preco">R$</span>
      <span class="Texto-Preco">50,00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Container">
  <div class="Thumb-Produto">
    <img src="http://www.oqvestir.com.br/Imagens/produtos/23/00054123/00054123_Vitrine.jpg" />
    <div class="Thumb-Preco">
      <span class="Moeda-Preco">R$</span>
      <span class="Texto-Preco">150,00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
  <INPUT CLASS="FILTRO" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="OP1" />R$ 0,00 - 100,00
  <INPUT CLASS="FILTRO" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="OP2" />R$ 100,00 - 150,00
  <INPUT CLASS="FILTRO" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="OP3" />R$ 150,00 - 200,00
</form>
```

Link para o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boap5h1q/)

Comment: Obrigado Wakim, deu certo aqui, jamais chegaria nesse resultado, sou iniciante em programação e não tenho nenhum curso, nem nada, estou tentando aprender aos poucos, em vídeo aulas na internet e e através de maravilho fórum. Mais uma vez obrigado.